# Not being able to read / accept / set browser cookies in React js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I am having an endpoint in my express js app that sets cookies to the response, the code is as below,

```
router.get("/products?", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { category, productId, page = 1, limit = 10 } = req.query;
    let query = {};

    if (category) {
      query = { categories: category };
    } else if (productId) {
      query = { _id: productId };

      const recentlyViewed = req.cookies.recentlyViewed || [];
      const index = recentlyViewed.indexOf(productId);

      if (index !== -1) {
        recentlyViewed.splice(index, 1);
      }

      recentlyViewed.unshift(productId);

      res.cookie("recentlyViewed", recentlyViewed, {
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        domain: "localhost:3000",
      });
    }

    const count = await Product.countDocuments(query);
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(count / limit);
    const currentPage = parseInt(page);

    if (currentPage > totalPages) {
      throw new UDError({
        status: 404,
        message: "Requested resource does not exist",
      });
    }

    const products = await Product.find(query)
      .limit(limit)
      .skip((currentPage - 1) * limit);

    res.status(200).json({
      products,
      totalPages,
      currentPage,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

So here I am using res.cookie to set a cookie with Key recentlyViewed to the response. And from my react frontend I am trying to access / read this cookie from the response using the package jsCookie. However I am always getting undefined and the cookies are not getting set in the browser. When I try from the postman its working fine without any issues.
Could you guys please help me with the right way to access and set cookies at the frontend using React js.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProductDetails = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_URL}/api/v1/public/products?productId=${id}`,
        { withCredentials: true }
      );
      if (response.data.products.length) {
        setProductDetails(response.data.products[0]);
      }
      const similarProductResponse = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_URL}/api/v1/public/products?category=${response.data.products[0].categories[0]}`
      );
      if (similarProductResponse.data.products.length) {
        setSimilarProducts(similarProductResponse.data.products);
      }
      console.log(response);
      const recentlyViewed = Cookies.get("recentlyViewed");
      console.log(recentlyViewed);
    };
    fetchProductDetails();
  }, [id]);
```